# Best practice to implement method getXXX from db using cursor for Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-cursor

For example code below. Do we need to close cursor? Do we better use try/catch/finally instead of using if()?

```
public int getCount() {


    final Cursor countCursor = contentResolver.query(
            AnalyticContract.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] {"count(*) AS count"},
            null,
            null,
            null);
    if (countCursor == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    countCursor.moveToFirst();
    final int count = countCursor.getInt(0);
    return count;
}
```

The try-with-resources statement is a try statement that declares one or more resources. A resource is an object that must be closed after the program is finished with it. The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement. Any object that implements java.lang.AutoCloseable, which includes all objects which implement java.io.Closeable, can be used as a resource.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: Yes you need to close that cursor because it goes out of scope. The construction to use is up to you. Personally I prefer a try/finally construction when there's a cursor involved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I believe is primarily opinion-based. It depends I guess on coder's preference and the circumstances.

I have always preferred the `if (cursor != null)` or vice versa approach. Unless something truly spectacular has happened; which will be handled by `throws Exception`, I'd use if-else checks wherever I want the reader/reviewer to see which parts are *really and truly* exceptions and which are occurrences of different possible/valid scenarios.

---

This brings us to the current problem of `Curosr` and applying null checks.

AFAIK (since mostly a `Cursor` is related with a `SQLiteDatabase`) a `ContentResolver.query()` should never return a null `Cursor` if the query itself is valid unless in case of an invalid query which is a real exception and you should instead get an Exception.

So in my opinion the best approach would be using your example either

```
public int getCount() throws Exception {

    Cursor countCursor;
    try {
        countCursor = contentResolver.query(
                AnalyticContract.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] {"count(*) AS count"},
                null,
                null,
                null);

        countCursor.moveToFirst();
        return countCursor.getInt(0);
    }
    finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Or a variation where Exception is caught and handled within the method itself.

---

Now to answer your second question whether or not you *should* `close()` a `Cursor`: you should always close a `Cursor`. Whenever you don't have need for it. If you delve deeper into any of the `Cursor.close()` method-implementations. Since `Curosr` is an interface which in case of SQLite is implemented by `SQLiteCursor` you will notice that this method releases any and all allocations held by it.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to make a database helper class and through that database access becomes much much easier. Sample of a database helper Class -

```
public class DatabaseHelperClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public DatabaseHelperClass(Context context)
{
    super(context,"hakeem.db",null,1);
}

//Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("Your SQL Query to create a table");
   }


//Delete Tables
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("drop table table_name if exists");
    onCreate(db);
}

//Insertion of data into tables
long insertData(Various Parameters you like to pass for insertion)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();

values.put("col_name1",value);
values.put("col_name2",value);
values.put("col_name3",value);
values.put("col_name4",value);

    return db.insert("signup_details",null,values);
}

//Delete record
public int deleteData(int id)
{
    SQLiteDatabase sb=getWritableDatabase();
    return sb.delete("hospital_details","id="+id,null);
}


//Update data in table
int updateData(Parameters you want to pass for update. Make sure you include a primary key)
{
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();

     values.put("col_name1",value);
     values.put("col_name2",value);
      values.put("col_name3",value); 
      values.put("col_name4",value);

    return getWritableDatabase().update("signup_details",values,"id="+id,null);
}



//Read data from tables
Cursor getSigninDetails() { return getWritableDatabase().rawQuery("select  * from table_name",null); }
}
```

and to access results from the database-

```
 private void getDataFromDatabase() {

    Cursor cursor = db.getUserData();

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            var_name1= cursor.getString(0);
            var_name2= cursor.getString(1);
            var_name3= cursor.getString(2);
            var_name4= cursor.getString(3);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
cursor.close();

}
```